# Capturar e mudar o valor de uma coluna de sua respectiva linha em uma tabela com inúmeras linhas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

[image: #1]

Os futuros dados da tabela serão mostrados através do código abaixo:

```
<?php
while($linhaAssociativa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
            { ?>
<tr>
  <td class="cmenu2"><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["CommonName"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["RealAddress"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["BytesSent"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["BytesReceived"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["VirtualAddress"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Since"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Status"]?></td>
</tr>
<?php
            } ?>
```

Onde cada linha é um **cliente** e possui uma coluna status(é a última coluna de cada linha) com o valor **0** ou **1**.

[image: #2]

Estou usando um [plugin](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) de **contextMenu** para criar um menu *Bloquear/Desbloquear* ao clicar na primeira coluna de cada linha e um [plugin](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) de **confirm** ao clicar em bloquear (imagem 3).

[image: #3]

**O que eu estou tentando fazer**: quando clicar com o botão direito em cima de uma linha, se a opção for **bloquear** o status que era **0** virará **1**, caso **desbloquear** **1** virará **0**. Posteriormente eu pegarei a informação da *td* que guardará o valor do status (0 ou 1) e jogarei num banco de dados - mas isso aparentemente é fácil.
**O que eu não estou conseguindo fazer**: Se eu clicar com o botão direito em **Garret Winters** o contextMenu do plugin irá abrir e se for clicado em bloquear, 0 virará 1. Porém eu não sei repetir a lógica para todas as outras linhas (**Winters** e todas as outras linhas abaixo).

---

O código das funções:

```
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'NOME DO SELETOR', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "bloquear": {name: "Bloquear", icon: "edit"},
            "desbloquear": {name: "Desbloquear", icon: "cut"},


        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })    
});
```

**E**

```
$.confirm({
    title:"Você tem certeza?",
    content:"Você REALMENTE tem certeza que quer bloquear este cliente?",
    confirmButton: 'Eu quero',
    cancelButton: 'Não, nunca!',
    confirm: function(){
      $.alert('Ok... Como o senhor quiser');
    }
  });
```

---

**Tentando deixar o mais claro possível** - Digamos que a tabela tenha 10 linhas, e cada linha contenha uma coluna NOME e uma coluna STATUS (por padrão com valor 0). Se eu clicar na primeira linha com o botão direito e ir em bloquear, ele vai mudar o STATUS (o td de classe **cmenu2**) para 1. **PORÉM** se eu coloco o td da segunda linha também como classe cmenu2 e tento aplicar a lógica como eu mostrei em fotos/código, e clicar com o botão direito na linha dois, ir em bloquear, ele vai alterar o status da linha um e não da dois!

Comment: O seletor usado é a classe `.cmenu2`?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida Então, dentro do while, onde é criado tr e td's, o último td tem como classe cmenu2. Só que se todas as linhas (são mais de 200 linhas) ter a última coluna (Status) como classe cmenu2, ao clicar com o direito e ir em bloquear, ele vai mudar o valor de 0 para 1 em todas as colunas Status e todas as linhas..

Comment: Pra mim funcionou corretamente. O problema pode ser o uso com o plugin do DataTables.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida o que exatamente funcionou para você brother? Veja novamente o que eu não estou conseguindo fazer... Acho que não consigo explicar melhor.

Comment: "Porém eu não sei repetir a lógica para todas as outras linhas". Isso funcionou como esperado. O plugin funciona para todas as linhas com a classe `.context-menu-one`, que é a do exemplo do site https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Comment: Eu inseri o código que usei para teste. Em todas as linhas geradas o menu de contexto aparece quando eu clico com o botão direito do mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei as amostras do banco de dados Sakila do MySQL.

No script abaixo, a última coluna tem um menu de contexto. Quando você clicar nele, aparecerão as opções de bloquear e desbloquear. Finalmente, quando você clicar na opção desejada, o valor dela será mostrado, aí você pode fazer o que quiser com ele.

Dica: faça bom uso das funções **callback** disponíveis no plugin.

```html
<?php
include 'conexao.php';

$query = 'select first_name, last_name from sakila.actor limit 10';

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>:: Login</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.2.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-5" id="login-container">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                    <?php
                    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r['first_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="context-menu-one"><?php echo $r['last_name']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.2.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.2.0/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                
                function createSomeMenu() {
                    return {
                        callback: function(key, options) {
                            var m = "clicked: " + key;
                            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
                        },
                        items: {
                            "bloquear": {name: "Bloquear", icon: "edit"},
                            "desbloquear": {name: "Desbloquear", icon: "cut"}
                        }
                    };
                }
                
                $('.context-menu-one').on('mouseup', function(e){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    // store a callback on the trigger
                    $this.data('runCallbackThingie', createSomeMenu);
                    var _offset = $this.offset(),
                        position = {
                            x: _offset.left + 10, 
                            y: _offset.top + 10
                        }
                    // open the contextMenu asynchronously
                    setTimeout(function(){ $this.contextMenu(position); }, 1000);
                });

                // setup context menu
                $.contextMenu({
                    selector: '.context-menu-one',
                    trigger: 'none',
                    build: function($trigger, e) {
                        // pull a callback from the trigger
                        return $trigger.data('runCallbackThingie')();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

O código ficou como pode ser visto. Eu não tomei precaução alguma com o PHP, porque o objetivo era trazer os dados do banco da dados.

Comment: Ok. E como eu capturo o valor do td da linha que eu clicar com o direito e clicar em bloquear de acordo com todas as imagens e código que mandei? É isto que não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Se na tabela há 10 linhas, e em cada linha contém uma coluna chamada NOME e uma coluna chamada STATUS. Status por padrão está como 0 (DESBLOQUEADO). Se eu clicar com o botão direito na primeira linha e ir em bloquear, o status do primeiro nome irá para 1 e as outras 9 linhas permanecem intactas. Porém, com o código que coloquei, se nas 10 linhas, na coluna STATUS eu coloco como classe cmenu2 e chamo aquela função, ele vai alterar SEMPRE o td da primeira linha, independente de qual linha eu clique com o direito.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta pra tentar deixar mais claro possível.

Comment: Editei o código com o exemplo do site (documentação do JQuery contextMenu). https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/async-create.html

Comment: segue o seguinte html `<tr>
                            <td>first_name</td>
                            <td class="context-menu-one">0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some_name</td>
                            <td class="context-menu-one">1</td>
                        </tr>`

A primeira tr tem a segunda td como valor 0.
A segunda tr tem a segunda td como o valor 1.
Quando eu clicar em bloquear na primeira tr-segunda td, como faço para exibir "0"? Quando eu clicar em bloquear na segunda tr como faço para exibir "1"?

Answer (score -1):

Mano vc se é só pra exibir, vc pode dar uma id pra essas td e pegar o valor delas com 'document.getElementById(id).value;', coloca esse código dentro de um 'alert' que dá bom.

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Comment: Foi mal mano, eu só fui perceber hoje onde que fica o campo de comentários.